# How do I read this damage notation?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage

In Dungeons and Dragons if a monster attacks and hits what happens with this damage: 4(1d4+2)? Do you add inside the parenthesis then multiply by 4?

Answer (score 6):

What's being presented is the expected outcome (4, rounded down) of the damage roll (1d4+2). This means that if you'd like to roll the damage you'll roll a four-sided die and add 2 to the roll. If you want to save yourself a roll, just use 4 as the damage.